# Getting the content of a link without clicking it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am new to JavaScript. I want to do this.

1. I am in `A.com/`.
2. There is a link as `A.com/B` in `A.com/`  (can see the link in the content of `A.com/`).
3. There is another link as `A.com/B/C` when I am in `A.com/B`  (it is not in the content of `A.com/` . It can be seen in the content of `A.com/B/`)

What I need is to get the link `A.com/B/C` when I am in `A.com/`.

My idea is if there is a way to load the content of `A.com/B` without clicking it, then I can do a simple search i that content and find the link `A.com/B/C`.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: For security reasons, you can't do that.

Comment: "Getting the content of a link without clicking it" is that what cannot be done ?

Comment: No.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy.  You need to learn about AJAX.

Comment: @SLaks , you sure it cant be done ? ?

Comment: @PratikJoshi: Read that page.

Comment: As SLaks said, it couldn't be accomplished on the client-side, but could be done on the server-side

Comment: Except possibly through CORS http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: It can be done with Ajax. As we're only working from A.com to A.com. The link about same-origin policy explicitly state that it's possible. (First two line of the table is exactly what we're trying to do here). And there is no need to CORS, there is no cross domain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you are working from/to the same domain, you can achieve some Ajax to get content from another page (on the same domain).

With jQuery, you could do something like that :

```
var href = $("a").attr("href");
$.get(href, function( data ){
    console.log( data ); //will log the html.
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Could you explain this little bit to me ? :)

Comment: I mean where to put "B" and "C" ?

Comment: This makes an Ajax request. Just set `href` with the url you want. `/B, `A.com/B`, `./B/C`...

Comment: If I have not mistaken I ran this code to get the content of a profile `var href = $("a").attr("http://stackoverflow.com/users/3693167/user3693167");
$.get(href, function( data ){
    console.log( data ); //will log the html.
});`
But it logs the content of this very page not that link. Whys is that ? :)